# URL Rewrite problem ,Regex expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

In my appication i used to URL Rewrite using Intelligencia.
My URL Pattern is

```
<rewrite url="~/([A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+)$" to="~/xxxxxx.aspx?id=$1"/>
```

Now i want if the URL doesn't contain **iphonestatelist,iphonepropertytype** then only it should redirect.

I have used this below code but it does not working.

```
<rewrite url="~/(^((?!\b(iphonestatelist|iphonepropertytype)\b).)*[A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+)$" to="~/xxxxxx.aspx?id=$1"/>
```

Eg:
The below URL dont want to Rewrite

**www.xxxx.com/abc/sef/iphonestatelist**

The right URL to Rewrite

**www.xxxx.com/FX1234**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<rewrite
   url="^(?!.*?\b(?:iphonestatelist|iphonepropertytype)\b)~/([A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+)$" 
   to="~/xxxxxx.aspx?id=$1"
/>
```

---

Generally: To check if a string contains (or does not contain) a certain sub-string, use a look-ahead (or negative look-ahead, respectively) like this:

```
^(?=.*?pattern-reqired)pattern-you-look-for
^(?!.*?pattern-disallowed)pattern-you-look-for
```

These patterns can also be chained

```
^(?!.*?not-this)(?!.*?not-that)pattern-you-look-for
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
   `<rewrite
   url="^(?!.*?\b(?:iphonestatelist|iphonepropertytype)\b)~/([A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+)$" 
   to="~/xxxxxx.aspx?id=$1"
/>`

Generally: To check if a string contains (or does not contain) a certain sub-string, use a look-ahead (or negative look-ahead, respectively) like this:

```
`^(?=.*?pattern-reqired)pattern-you-look-for
```

^(?!.*?pattern-disallowed)pattern-you-look-for
These patterns can also be chained

^(?!.*?not-this)(?!.*?not-that)pattern-you-look-for`